# Runtime of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, big-o-notation

I have an algorithm with running time that satisfies
$$ T(n) \leq n + \frac{1}{n}\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}(T(i) + T(n-i)),$$ and $T(0) = 0$. I was able to show that $T(n) = \mathcal O(n\log n)$ with a leading constant $c > 4$.

I modified this algorithm such that the recursion for $T(n)$ now satisfies
$$ T(n) \leq 3 \log n + n + \frac{3}{n}\sum^{2n/3}_{i=n/3}(T(i) + T(n-i)),$$ and $T(0) = 0$. Intuitively, this algorithm should also be $\mathcal O(n\log n)$ but with a better leading constant, but I haven't been able to show it. Any ideas?

Comment: "with a better leading constant": what do you mean ??

Comment: What is your base case $T(0)$?

Comment: @AspiringMatL T(0) = 0.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: With 0< c < 4